# Finding 'The Five Tenets' Dark Brotherhood book?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to find interesting books to put in my bookshelves so they're not all... empty and stuff. I saw a reference to a book named The Five Tenets, a Dark Brotherhood book. I looked at the wiki for any locations of it, and it's only found in the two sanctuaries. I can't seem to find it in the Dark Brotherhood sanctuary though and I don't want to put everything on it being in the Dawnstar Sanctuary without knowing for sure that it will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Five Tenets can be found in one of these locations:

- Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary
- Fort Farragut(Only in the Dawnguard DLC),
- Dawnstar Sanctuary

Comment: I didn't know Vicente Valtieri appeared in Skyrim.

Comment: go and kill the orphan boys target in the orphanage in windhelm them you'll meet Vicente Valtieri after you join them,put garlic into his pocket by pick pocketing then it will slowly kill him then you take the book and leave

Comment: @Sandokan then you didnt explore skyrim as much as i did...(skyrim freak) ;)

Comment: you will or may certainly find it with Cicero at the Dawnstar Sanctuary

Comment: [Are you sure there's a Vicente Valtieri NPC in the vanilla game?](http://www.uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=vicente+valtieri&fulltext=Search&ns134=1&ns146=1&ns142=1&talkpages=1&redirs=1&profile=advanced)

Comment: yes,there is an update and a mod to put him in the game.he isn't there by default though,but he carries the book

Comment: Mentioning him is just confusing if you don't say which mod adds him and where.

Comment: Aside from Vicente Valtieri, [Fort Farragut](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Fort_Farragut) also didn't appear in vanilla Skyrim (unless there's a way to travel to Cyrodiil from Skyrim that I didn't know). They both appeared in TES IV: Oblivion only.

Comment: what are you talking about,fort farragut appeared in skyrim's vanilla.

Comment: @ian__escobar "*fort farragut appeared in skyrim's vanilla*" Could you link to a source? Like a UESP or TES wiki article? [The UESP wiki doesn't seem to say anything about a Fort Farragut in Skyrim.](http://www.uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=Fort+Farragut&fulltext=Search&ns134=1&ns146=1&ns142=1&talkpages=1&redirs=1&profile=advanced)

Comment: http://skyrim.gamepedia.com/Fort_Farragut

Comment: @ian__escobar That page states: "*Fort Farragut was a ruined, abandoned Imperial Fortress which stood just northeast of the city of Cheydinhal, in the Imperial Province of northeastern Cyrodiil.*" Cheydinhal is a city in Cyrodiil (where most of TES IV: Oblivion took place), *not* Skyrim.